# Ubuntu 15.10: restoring USB storage access

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel

Starting ok situation: running Ubuntu 15.10 with kernel 4.2.0-22-generic.

I have an external USB 3.0 Icybox with 4 SATA drives which all contribute to a ZFS pool; as I updated to -21 my openzfs modules weren't loading and I messed up, creating conflicts between openzfs repository, dkms and ubuntu-provided openzfs but I've been able to revert to a correct config and keep original kernel (-16) and newest one (-22).

Now both are working with latest zfs (0.6.5.3) which is normally loaded (see below for complete lsmod output).

problem: USB storage is not handled properly.

external usb storage is recognized:

```
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0951:16a7 Kingston Technology
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 152d:0539 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JMS539/567 SuperSpeed SATA II/III 3.0G/6.0G Bridge
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

(Bus 4 Device 3 is a USB key and device, bus 2 device 2 is my abovementioned icybox).

point is that I see no additional sdx devices created in /dev/ nad I'm conseequently unable to access any USB storage device (whether it's a USB key or my Icybox).

here's the complete output of lsmod:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
zfs                  2805760  0
zunicode              331776  1 zfs
zcommon                57344  1 zfs
znvpair                90112  2 zfs,zcommon
spl                   102400  3 zfs,zcommon,znvpair
zavl                   16384  1 zfs
kvm_intel             167936  0
kvm                   512000  1 kvm_intel
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
aesni_intel           167936  0
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20480  2 aesni_intel,ablk_helper
serio_raw              16384  0
autofs4                40960  2
e1000e                237568  0
ahci                   36864  2
libahci                32768  1 ahci
ptp                    20480  1 e1000e
pps_core               20480  1 ptp
```

same behavior whether I load -16 or -22. I already tried to reinstall both kernel image and headers from aptitude.

USB-related lines in dmesg:

```
[   13.799439] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[   13.818939] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0539
[   13.818946] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=10, Product=11, SerialNumber=5
[   13.818960] usb 2-2: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI Bridge
[   13.818962] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: JMicron
[   13.818963] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 000000000000
[   17.315714] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[ 3416.725055] usb 4-1.6: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[ 3416.823645] usb 4-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=16a7
[ 3416.823652] usb 4-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 3416.823668] usb 4-1.6: Product: Dell USB
[ 3416.823671] usb 4-1.6: Manufacturer: Dell
[ 3416.823674] usb 4-1.6: SerialNumber: 001E8C88A18EBE8081CA267B
```

Can someone please help me troubleshooting what the problem is?

thank you very much!
Alessandro